Trying to track this fuction so after the program runs x times, a thing happens
I made this Russian roulette game for my project. I turned it into a function and now I want to track. I want for example, after 150 times the "gun" will jam. I also want to track the output so I can graph, which number occurs most frequently etc.
myList = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"]
import random
#shuffliing the list, kinda like spinning the drum thing on a revolver
random.shuffle(myList)
print(myList)

#randomly selecting a number to shoot first
shoot = random.choice(myList)
def russianRoullete(shoot,myList):
    trigPull = 0
    
    while trigPull < 6:
        input("Press enter to pull the trigger")
    #code below makes sure a chamber thats been "shot" wont be picked again!
        shoot1=random.randrange(len(myList))
        shoot2 = myList.pop(shoot1)
        #program runs this and it "shoots" the gun
        print("You pulled the trigger on chamber", shoot2)
        trigPull+=1
    
        if shoot2 == "6":
            print("BANG! Game over.")
            break
        else:
            print("Click... You survived this time.")

result = russianRoullete(shoot, myList)
print(result)


Cool, what is preventing you from doing this? Can you include the code you've tried for this? What happens when you run it? What did you expect to happen instead? Any errors? See [ask].

@CrankyNanky Hi ,there. Did the answer end up working the intended way?
